# Unresponsive Trackpad Click After Battery Depletion

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, trackpad

I had a very odd situation happen with my machine at the weekend and wondered if anyone could shed some light on it.

I have an early 2013 Retina MacBook Pro and I was watching a DVD on it using the internal battery power.

I had my magic mouse connected via bluetooth, a Superdrive attached via USB and my UE Boom speaker attached via bluetooth.

Basically the battery ran out and the machine immediately shutdown when the power ran out.

However, when I plugged in the wall wart charger to charge the machine and carry on watching the Trackpad click wasn't functioning.  What was really odd was the cursor moved fine but none of the clicking worked (either the tap or the actual click on the trackpad).  Also what appeared really odd was placing the cursor over any of the window icons in the top left (the close, maximise, minimise) buttons didn't show the X, +, - glyphs as it usually does.

I rebooted the OS multiple times (I think 5) until it actually worked again.

This makes no sense to me at all.  Anyone else seen this?

Comment: Is OSX not able to automatically shut down based on battery power?  Surely it can?  Every PC laptop I've ever used can handle this situation ...

Answer (score 1):

Usually OS X machines will go to sleep when they run low on battery.

The fact that yours didn't suggests a battery fault.

I used to be a technician and I saw clicking affected when the battery swells (as the battery sits directly on top of the trackpad assembly).

Does the click feel normal (still get the normal click noise when you press the trackpad)? If not, I would suggest taking it in to be looked at by a technician.